# NSDecimal multiplication

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a core data-based app that stores several properties in the `decimal` and `float` data types.  I'm writing some transient properties / virtual accessors that run calculations and return some derived numbers, but I can't seem to get NSDecimalNumber multiplication to work.

Why does this not work:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)discountedPrice {
return ([self.orderCost decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:self.discountPercentage]);
}
// Error: Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSNumber *', expected 'struct NSDecimalNumber *' when passing argument 1 of 'decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:' from distinct ...
```

When this does:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)orderCost {
    return ([self.orderCost decimalNumberByAdding:self.taxes]);
}
```

I assume that my object gets an `NSNumber` from core data regardless of the storage type specified in the data model, so why does this puke and how can I make it work?  Am I completely misunderstanding this here?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

You're running into problems because `-decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:` expects an NSDecimalNumber, but (I presume) you're passing it an NSNumber containing a `float` or `double` value (your discount percentage). Try building an NSDecimalNumber first:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)discountedPrice {
    NSDecimalNumber *dec = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:
                              [self.discountPercentage decimalValue]];
    return ([self.orderCost decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:dec]);
}
```